# I have a wrapper that has width of 1240px and an image which has 1240px of empty space in the middle of it. How to place it so the wrapper covers it?

Tags: html, css

Currently I have a wrapper which has a set width of 1240px. As you can imagine, this means the 1240 pixels on the center of my page are always covered by the wrapper.

I also have an image with width of 3160 px ( 1920px image size which is cut in the middle and separated by 1240px of empty space ).

Now I want to make that image the background-image of my body BUT in a way that the 1240px of empty space in the image is hidden behind the 1240px wrapper. This way every part of my image would be shown and nothing would be hidden behind the wrapper besides the 1240px of empty space.

Also I understand that some of the image will be hidden. By my calculations people with 1920x1080px monitors will only see 340 px of the image to the left and 340px of the image to the right. I have no problem with that.

How can I do that? The end result will look like this:

[image]

And this is the original image:

[image]

My code. You gotta open the code in full screen to see it the way it is meant to be seen:

```css
*, *:after, *:before {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
   -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
    background-color: #eaeaea;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hd35U.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
}
.wrapper {
    width: 1240px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: red;
    height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<div class='wrapper'>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
*, *:after, *:before {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    body {
        background-color: #eaeaea;
        height: 100vh;
        width: 100vw;
        background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hd35U.jpg');
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: 100% 100%;
    }
    .wrapper {
        width: 50%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        background-color: red;
        height: 100%;
    }
```

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<div class='wrapper'>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this images

[image]

this image result

[image]